# How should I manage my screens in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, user-controls

So I'm rewriting a windows forms project.
The old project had few issues. These are some I'm trying to fix right now.

My problems:

1. **Everything** was on panels on one form. Switching screens in the code was done by hiding/unhiding these panels.
2. General slow performance across screens.
3. Poor data coupling.

My solutions:

1. Break up screens into user controls (hereon just refered to as 'screen(s)'). My main form has 3 components on it, a nav bar, title bar and 'view port'(an empty, docked, panel).
2. I will keep only one screen/user control (hereon just refered to as 'screen') in memory and docked in the view port. This is done by just initializing a screen and popping it into the view port panel on the main form. Changing screens will simply be destroying the current screen in the view port and initializing a new one in it's place. This isn't to reduce memory usage but rather active components, as what I understand, slows down the old winforms project, is the fact that winforms uses the cpu to render.
3. This is where the subjectively fun part comes in. If a controller/presenter(from mvc/mvp type patterns)/code changes business data, the screen that is displaying that data needs to be updated. Since there will be only one screen displayed at one time, I will now need to go check if the screen affected by the data is currently initialized and update the screen. I think checking which screen uses a piece of data and checking if that screen is active and then changing the appropriate visual component, for each piece of data will be moronic.
   So when I initialize a screen I will just bind (with data binding) all of it's controls to my global state. This feels perfect since I will have some services impacting my state with their own controller, and the changes will be handled the same as a ui event changing the data. This is also great since my data layer will need to propegate to rather (for me) complex databases, so keeping the data layer clean will help.

My questions:

1. Am I managing my screens properly? Is it a good solution to slow performing winforms software?
2. Should I use data binding to achieve this? In this case it will be my sole source of view data, and I've read that data binding should be used in moderation. What am I missing.

I'm quite green and this job is my first C# bout. Although I have done java and flutter/dart before.
Also if there is a better place to ask these types of questions, I would appreciate a point in the right direction. There isn't any/other/senior/superior software engineers at work who I can ask these types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Working with relatively complex software, communicating over ethernet with hardware devices here.

I prefer having many many small windows that save their position when closed and restore their previous position when opened so that users can arrange them as needed.

Since I work with relatively slowly updating data, I periodically keep updating the data in the controls, unless they are focused (eg. potentially currently being edited).

Sure, with this, the data might be inconsistent sometimes, but no one will notice in the 50ms timeframe until the next update.

Since this is done for practically all my controls, the logic can also be centralized beautifully.

This, of course, goes against the binding paradigm but it's my development style which also works well for other programming languages.